# Can't query IDirect3D7 from IDirectDraw7 in Win10

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm trying the following code:

```
hr = ddr7->QueryInterface(IID_IDirect3D7,(void**)&d3d7)
```

the hr returned is E_NOINTERFACE, how does this happen?

Comment: When did this ever work?

Comment: this link say it work : http://idlebeaver.ninja/dx7/devdoc/live/directx/imover_3p9g.htm

Comment: Ah, right, that was how it worked 20+ years ago... Direct3D 8 and before were purged from the legacy DirectX SDK back in November 2007. The samples for Direct3D 7 were gone a long time before that. Starting with Direct3D 8, you had a distinct ``Direct3DCreate`` helper.

Comment: What were the parameters given to ``DirectDrawCreateEx`` to create the ``ddr7`` object in this case? I believe you have to use ``DDCREATE_HARDWAREONLY``.

Comment: nullptr. I just tried DDCREATE_HARDWAREONLY and DDCREATE_EMULATIONONLY , not work.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 system Version 1909 (18363) [x64], this worked fine:

```
#define INITGUID
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ddraw.h>
#include <d3d.h>

typedef HRESULT ( WINAPI* LPDIRECTDRAWCREATEEX )( GUID FAR * lpGuid, LPVOID  *lplpDD, REFIID  iid,IUnknown FAR *pUnkOuter );

void main()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstDDraw = nullptr;
    LPDIRECTDRAW pDDraw = nullptr;

    hInstDDraw = LoadLibraryW( L"ddraw.dll" );
    if( hInstDDraw )
    {
        auto pDDCreate = reinterpret_cast<LPDIRECTDRAWCREATEEX>(GetProcAddress( hInstDDraw, "DirectDrawCreateEx" ) );
        if (pDDCreate)
        {
            HRESULT hr = pDDCreate(nullptr, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pDDraw), IID_IDirectDraw7, nullptr);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                LPDIRECT3D7 d3d7 = nullptr;
                hr = pDDraw->QueryInterface(IID_IDirect3D7, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&d3d7));
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    printf("Worked\n");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("QI Failed: %08X\n", static_cast<int>(hr));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("DDCreate Failed: %08X\n", static_cast<int>(hr));
            }
        }

        FreeLibrary( hInstDDraw );
    }

    printf("Failed\n");
}
```

You should make sure the HRESULT from your call to `DirectDrawCreateEx` worked. Also, it's possible it could be an issue with your drivers or setup.

> Your original question really should include more code, particularly the `DirectDrawCreateEx` since the QueryInterface alone isn't particularly informative.

Comment: tried your code , failed ```QI Failed: 80004002
Failed``` and my Win10(1903) is older than yours

Comment: Then at this point I'd suspect your drivers or some other tool you have installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too, works fine on 32bit application but fails on 64bit application. I'm on Windows 10 x64 version 10.0.18363.1082. As others already commented, D3D7 is already obsolete.

Comment: Do you have an answer to that question?

Comment: Yes: It is not part of x64 version of Windows.